# UICollectionView Header title change

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `UICollectionView` with 4 custom `UICollectionViewCells`. In the header of the `UICollectionView` there's a `UISegmentedControl`. My goal is to change the header `UILabel` that plays the role of a title. Right now if the segmented control value had been changed, the cells are reloaded and the title should be switched, but it overlaps with the first title. I can't figure out why.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderDiscoverVC", for: indexPath) as! HeaderDiscoverVC
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 30)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("d9e2e7")
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 30))

        switch segReusableIdentifier {
        case "Reply":
            label.text = "Reply"
        case "Media":
            label.text = "Media"
        case "Likes":
            label.text = "Likes"
        case "Comments":
            label.text = "Comments"
        default:
            label.text = ""
        }
        label.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Bold, size: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.hex("8a9da6")
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }

   fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are adding the label to your header view.

You should put the headerView.addSubview(label) to your HeaderDiscoverVC Class. Also set the colour and font to the same class.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderDiscoverVC", for: indexPath) as! HeaderDiscoverVC
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 30)

    // MOVE THE COMMENTED LINE TO YOUR HeaderDiscoverVC
    //headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("d9e2e7")
    headerView.label.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 30)

    switch segReusableIdentifier {
    case "Reply":
        headerView.label.text = "Reply"
    case "Media":
        headerView.label.text = "Media"
    case "Likes":
        headerView.label.text = "Likes"
    case "Comments":
        headerView.label.text = "Comments"
    default:
        headerView.label.text = ""
    }

    // MOVE THE COMMENTED LINES TO YOUR HeaderDiscoverVC
    //label.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Bold, size: 16)
    //label.textColor = UIColor.hex("8a9da6")
    //headerView.addSubview(label)
    return headerView
}

fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
}
```

Try and share your results

Comment: Excellent! This is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `label` programmatically to the `headerView` which should be removed before adding again. `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView` do not remove programmatically added subviews.

In your code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderDiscoverVC", for: indexPath) as! HeaderDiscoverVC
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 30)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("d9e2e7")

        ///// Add below code to remove all subviews first before adding any new subview programmatically 
        for label in headerView.subviews {
            if let mylabel = label as? UILabel {
                mylabel.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        ////////////////
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 30))

        switch segReusableIdentifier {
        case "Reply":
            label.text = "Reply"
        case "Media":
            label.text = "Media"
        case "Likes":
            label.text = "Likes"
        case "Comments":
            label.text = "Comments"
        default:
            label.text = ""
        }
        label.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Bold, size: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.hex("8a9da6")
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }

   fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
}
```

Better approach will be to keep the `label` in `HeaderDiscoverVC` and use it in the code as:

```
 headerView.label.text = "Your data"
```

In this way you don't have to remove `subViews` programmatically.